# Jenkins PipelineShared library using Java

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

I know using Groovy, Jenkins Pipeline Shared library can be developed.

I want to know if there is any way the same Jenkins pipeline shared library can be developed using Java or any other technology?

Comment: Do you have chance read this: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Comment: Yes. I see only way is using groovy only.

Answer (score 2):

You build [groovy shared library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) and import your Java library by using Grab.
See example how to import yaml library:

```
@Grab(group = 'org.yaml', module='snakeyaml', version = "1.18")
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
```

Be sure that library jar file in Jenkins classpath.
Works for me with Jenkins 2.150.1

Comment: No. I want to build shared library using Java instead of Groovy. Is that possible?